# How to implement a splash screen with a progress bar? - android

Tags: java, android, timer, progress-bar, splash-screen

i have a splash screen at start up. with the following coding

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while (logoTimer<5000){
                    sleep(100);
                    logoTimer=logoTimer+100;
                     }
                startActivity(new Intent("com.package.MAIN"));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            finally{
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start();
}}
```

now i just want to add a **horizontal progress bar** to the above splash activity say at the bottom of the screen.. *so as the splash screen appears simultaneously the progress bar should load and when it finishes the next activity should appear.*

searched few examples on progress bar but was not able to do what i want. there were many examples for progress bar with a dialog box. but here i don't want any dialog box. i just need a plain **horizontal progress bar** on my splash screen.

so can someone help me out with required coding and stuffs? pls ! :)

Comment: Don't use 'splash screens' just for the sake of it. At the very least a 'splash screen' might be of use when performing a time consuming task but even then they're usually unnecessary. Yours serves no purpose other than to delay the user's access to your app by 5 seconds as far as I can tell. Not good for the UX. See this blog for why...http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632

Comment: Do you know how to measure loading progress? A progress bar is pointless if you cannot update it meaningfully every 10% or so.

Comment: I answered this question in below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020909/4896539

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go, wrote a tutorial how to create a SplashScreen with a progress bar:

http://blog.blundellapps.com/tut-splashscreen-with-progress-bar/

Basically instead of your thread it starts an ASyncTask, you pass a reference to your progressSpinner into the ASyncTask and this will update it as the thread is downloading resources (or whatever you want to do)

Comment: These days you are best using something like a cancellable coroutine scoped to the viewmodel, that way if your app is quit during the splashscreen it won't reopen when the background task finishes.

Answer (score -1):

This XML example will create a horizontal ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progress="0" />
```