# How to create a splash screen with percentage progress bar?

Tags: android

I want to show a splash screen for my application at start through a progress bar with `actual` load % of the application.

I have following requirement/queries -

1. Which component I should use to show progress bar
2. How to calculate the % load if splash screen itself is a part of application
3. On touch of splash screen I want to highlight the progress bar

Comment: what have you done so far??

Comment: if you have an app that takes long enough to load you feel the need to have a splash screen you should probably reconsider your ap

Comment: First of all mainly splash screen is used when u have to download data from server/web which will be used further into your app. And answer to your question: for showing % load you must know the TOTAL SIZE( in kb/mb) on which you can calculate and show the progress. So in your case what you are doing in Splash screen? explain. or you just want to show dummy %load? please explain so that we can help out. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040938/how-to-implement-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-android. Use a AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this: I tried this and this works with no errors

```
/**
 * Async class to get News
 * 
 */
protected class AsynchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... args) {

        download();

        return 1;
    }

    private void download() {
        // We are just imitating some process thats takes a bit of time
        // (loading of resources / downloading)
        int count = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            // Update the progress bar after every step
            int progress = (int) ((i / (float) count) * 100);
            publishProgress(progress);

            // Do some long loading things
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar1.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer a) {
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```